# Shifting in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

What do I do to shift this line to the right or above without changing the co-ordinates?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} % Set default line width to 0.75pt

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,390); % Set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 390

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: according to @Max Snippe

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} % Set default line width to 0.75pt

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,390); % Set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 390

\begin{scope}[xshift={(5,0)}]

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use xshift and yshift before the coordinates: `\draw    [xshift=5pt,yshift=2pt](257.75,206) -- [xshift=5pt,yshift=2pt](398.5,205) ;`

Comment: i want to do this as a whole. like if there were 100 lines, i want to shift all of them together using a single xshift/yshift command

Comment: You can enclose your lines in a `\begin{scope}[shift={(<x>,<y>)}]` end `\end{scope}`. Note that you need the braces surrounding the coordinates in the argument of `shift` because otherwise the `,` will be seen as a key delimiter.

Comment: You could do as in the commented code just `\path (257.75,206) -- ++(-10pt,0)`, or some other distance instead of 10pt.

Comment: @MaxSnippe please see the edit. why isn't it working

Comment: The coordinates inside a `tikzpicture` is only relative to other things in that `tikzpicture`, not the frame/page. So if you have one `tikzpicture` that contains just `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);` and another one that contains just `\draw (120,0) -- (121,1);`, the two will look identical. As far as TeX is concerned, it just sees a box that is 1cm by 1cm. The way that box is positioned on the page is exactly the same as the way the letter `X` is positioned on the page, or an `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. so what is the fix

Comment: marmot's answer (which enlarges the diagram) is one option. I'll add another.

Comment: @afsara_ben If you consider one of the given answers sufficient, you can accept it by clicking the light-green check mark (✔) beside it, right underneath the votes. Note that this does not have to be the answer with the highest score, but rather the answer that you deem the best solution. I saw that you have not yet accepted any answer to any of your questions. Please consider doing so (this also grants you a badge).

Comment: @afsara_ben: don't you have a typo in your edit? Should be `shift={(5,0)}`, not `xshift={(5,0)}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As already pointed out by @marmot and @TorbjørnT., the coordinates you use in your `tikzpicture` environment are relative, and not absolute with respect to the page. There are a few ways to move the line with respect to the page.

Also in your M(N)WE you use `xshift={(<x>,<y>)}`, but `xshift` takes a dimension as argument. You should use `shift={(<x>,<y>)}` where you can set `<y>` to 0, or use `xshift=<x>`.

You could draw an invisible path that outlines approximately the entire page such that you can draw inside that path.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,overlay]
            \path (0,0) rectangle (600,390); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size

            \draw[help lines,step=20] (0,0) grid (600,390); % Optional grid

            \draw[red]    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;

            \begin{scope}[shift={({50*cos(60)},{50*sin(60)})}]

                \draw[red]    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;

            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This GIF shows multiple such displacements.

[image]

Without the grid this would be:

[image]

An other way could be to use the `overlay` option and draw everything within a `scope` that is `shift`ed with respect to a page coordinate.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,overlay]
%            \path (0,0) rectangle (600,390); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size
%        
%            \draw[help lines,step=20] (0,0) grid (600,390); % Optional grid
%        
%            \draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;
            \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
                \begin{scope}[shift={({50*cos(60)},{50*sin(60)})}]

                    \draw[]    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;

                \end{scope}
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This way your origin (`0,0`) is located on the bottom left corner of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The coordinates inside a `tikzpicture` is only relative to other things in that `tikzpicture`, not the frame/page. So if you have one `tikzpicture` that contains just `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);` and another one that contains just `\draw (120,0) -- (121,1);`, the two will look identical. As far as TeX is concerned, it just sees a box that is 1cm by 1cm. The way that box is positioned on the page is exactly the same as the way the letter `X` is positioned on the page, or an `\includegraphics`.

(This applies to the default behaviour, Max's answer demonstrates one way of drawing things relative to the page.)

So you can move a `tikzpicture` horizontally the same way you move an image say. For example by adding `\hspace{<dimension>}` right before it (which, depending on the context, might not be the best method for horizontal positioning).

For the vertical position, you can use the `baseline` key in the `tikzpicture` option. What this does is define which y-coordinate, of the coordinates inside the `tikzpicture`, that is placed on the baseline of the surrounding text. In your case, with `y=0.5pt,yscale=-1` and the y-coordinates of the line being about 205, `baseline=-102.5pt` will place the `\draw`n line itself on the baseline of the surrounding text. `baseline=-120pt` will move the `tikzpicture` up on the page, `baseline=-80pt` will move it down.

I suspect some of the other answers might be more useful for you, but I'll add this anyway.

Here is a frame with three different examples.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% 1: \hspace{1cm}, baseline=-120pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
foo\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,baseline=-120pt]

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205)coordinate(a) ;

\end{tikzpicture}bar


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% 2: \hspace{2cm}, baseline=-102.75pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

foo\hspace{2cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,baseline=-102.75pt]
%uncomment if require:
% \path (0,390); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 390

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205)coordinate(a) ;

\end{tikzpicture}bar


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% 3: \hspace{-1cm}, baseline=-80pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

foo\hspace{-1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,baseline=-80pt]
%uncomment if require:
% \path (0,390); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 390

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205)coordinate(a) ;

\end{tikzpicture}bar

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ti*k*Z always adds by default a bounding box that fits all elements of the picture. Therefore, as long as you only draw the line, the absolute coordinates are unimportant (but of course the relative ones are). However, at the very moment you add an invisible point relative to the line, the bounding box will adjust and the line will move.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,2,...,160}
{\begin{frame}{I'm floating ;-)}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,390); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 390

\draw    (257.75,206) -- (398.5,205) ;
\path (257.75,206) -- ++ (-\X,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]